# Examples of $\alpha$-Hölder functions with graphs of maximal Hausdorff dimension

Tags: examples-counterexamples, dimension-theory-analysis, holder-spaces, hausdorff-measure

Let $I=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ an $\alpha$-Hölder function for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$. It's known that $\Gamma_f = \{(x,f(x)): x\in I\}$, the graph of $f$, has Hausdorff dimension at most $2-\alpha$.

Is there a systematic way of producing explicit examples of $\alpha$-Hölder functions such that $\operatorname{dim}_H(\Gamma_f) = 2 - \alpha$?

If not, what are some examples for different values of $\alpha$? Of course, I'm not talking about $\alpha=1$.

Comment: I believe there are examples in the 1937 paper of Besicovitch and Ursell where that upper bound appears, but I don’t currently have access: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-12.45.18/full